# How to put text after the author in title

Tags: titling

I have one question regarding how to put text after the author in my document. This is my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt, fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[load=accepted]{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{t1enc}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\S}{\mathbb{S}}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields


 \usepackage{titling}
 \setlength\droptitle{-5cm}
 \renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\raisebox{-0.35\height}
  {\hspace*{-3cm}\includegraphics[width=4cm]{TUC}}\quad\sffamily 
  \begin{tabular}{l}  {\selectlanguage{english}{TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY OF 
  CRETE}}\\[3ex]{\selectlanguage{english} SCHOOL OF PRODUCTION ENGINEERING 
  AND  MANAGEMENT}\end{tabular}\vskip 24ex}


\renewcommand\maketitlehookb{\vskip 8ex}
 \renewcommand\maketitlehookc{\vfill}


\selectlanguage{english}

 \title{good}

 \author{good\\\\}




 \date{Fall Semester 2017}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\}

 \begin{document}
 \selectlanguage{english}
 \maketitle
 \pagenumbering{gobble}
```

I have included a picture with text next to it in the beginning of the first page and afterwords I have put the title and the author section. My question is how can I write some more text after the the author sectio, such as some more details about the lesson, the project and etc.

Thank you

Comment: MWE does not compile for me

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply add a linebreak (`//`) after author ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
     \title{good}

     \author{
         good \\[3ex]
         \begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
             \small
            \textsc{Technical University of Crete}
         \end{minipage} \quad
         \begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
             \small
            \textsc{School of Production Engineering and  Management}
         \end{minipage}
    }
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want all the information concentrated in the first page and being written horizontally.

Comment: @bazooka I have edited the code.